# Getting error while using nuxt-class-component

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, nuxt.js

I copy pasted the example code from `vue-class-component` examples directory (https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/vue-class-component) and getting this error with latest nuxt

```
Nuxt.js Error:

TypeError: Cannot read property '_init' of undefined
    at VueComponent (/Users/piyushchauhan/Documents/testcodes/nuxt-component/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:4167:11)
    at server-bundle.js:2252:17
    at F (~/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:35:0)
    at server-bundle.js:2247:22
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object._callee$ (.nuxt/server.js:53:65)
    at tryCatch (~/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:14)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (~/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:0)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (~/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:0)
    at step (~/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:0)
    at server-bundle.js:1105:13
```

Test repo: https://github.com/piyushchauhan2011/nuxt-component . Anything that can be done to fix the problem so that we can use es6 class syntax with vuejs in Nuxt project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Nuxt.js 1.0.0-alpha2 fixed the error.